# android reset timer multiple times

Tags: java, timer, countdowntimer

My first question!
I am trying to make an app where you have a random amount of time generated (between 1 second and 5 minutes) and it starts to count down from it. By pushing a button on the screen the timer resets to a new random time between the parameters and so on over and over again.

My problem is that it is using the method .cancel() that is in the countDownTimer class which only stops it. So when I generate a new random time and use the .start() method it starts the countdown and the old one to which I don't want.

```
package com.example.kasutaja.refugecamp;

import android.os.CountDownTimer;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;


public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

Button Start;
TextView textViewTime;
TextView textViewScore;
public boolean run=true;
public long milliss;
public long aeg;
public long score;
public int a;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Start=(Button)findViewById(R.id.Start );
    textViewTime=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textViewTime);
    textViewScore=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textViewScore);
    textViewTime.setText("00:00:00");
    aeg=Randoom();
    final CounterClass timer= new CounterClass(aeg,1000);
    Start.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {


            if (run) {

                System.out.println(aeg + " aeg");
                aeg = aeg - milliss;
                System.out.println(aeg + " aeg2");
                score = score + aeg;
                System.out.println(milliss + " milliss");
                System.out.println(score + " score");
                String hmse = String.format("%02d:%02d:%02d",  TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(score),
                        TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(score) -  TimeUnit.HOURS.toMinutes(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(score)),
                        TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(score) - TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(score)));

                textViewScore.setText(hmse);
                timer.cancel();
                aeg = Randoom();
                final CounterClass timer = new CounterClass(aeg, 1000);
                timer.start();

            }


        }

    });

    timer.start();

}

public long Randoom() {
    Random rand = new Random();
    long aeg = rand.nextInt(300000 - 5000) + 5000;
    return aeg;
}
public class CounterClass extends CountDownTimer{

    public CounterClass(long millisInFuture,long countDownInterval){
        super(millisInFuture,countDownInterval);
    }
    @Override
    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished){

        long millis =millisUntilFinished;

        String hms=String.format("%02d:%02d:%02d", TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(millis),
                TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millis)- TimeUnit.HOURS.toMinutes(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(millis)),
                TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(millis)-TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millis)));

        textViewTime.setText(hms);
        milliss=millis;
    }
}
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution.

Just have to reinitialize the

```
final CounterClass timer = new CounterClass(aeg, 1000);
```

in the onClick method
as

```
this.timer = new CounterClass(aeg, 1000);
```